# Timezone.now throwing a Type Error when overriding a save method

Tags: python, django-rest-framework

I am writing an API in Django Rest Framework- when using the POST method to create a new object, if the 'done' field is True and the 'done_date' is Null, I would like the 'done_date' to automatically be set to current time. Here's what I tried to do, overriding the save method in my models:

## In models.py

```py
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone


class Task(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    done = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    author_ip = models.GenericIPAddressField()
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    done_date = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('id',)

    def __str__(self):
        return '{} - {}'.format(self.pk, self.title)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.done and not self.done_date:
            self.done_date = timezone.now
        super(Task, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

However, this throws a "TypeError when calling Task.objects.create(). This may be because you have a writable field on the serializer class that is not a valid argument to `Task.objects.create()`. You may need to make the field read-only, or override the TaskSerializer.create() method to handle this correctly."
Now, I am fairly certain that it's related to timezone.now in the save method, could someone advise me on how to proceed? I apologise if it is a basic question, thanks!

Comment: Do you want to actually _call_ the function, `timezone.now()`?  Otherwise, you're just using the function object iself.

Comment: Wow, that was silly of me! Your solution worked, of course - thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you have to do is to call the `timezone.now()` function (with the parenthesis) 
alternatively, you could use: `auto_now=True` and set `editable=True`